# Return links which do not have an associated document in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, performance, aggregate

I have a collection of webpages stored in MongoDB. Each document contains at least a hostname and pathname value as well as an array of all links found in a field 'a'. The document only exists after an attempted visit, like so:

```
{
    _id:"deadbeefdeadbeef01234567",
    hostname:"www.example.com",
    pathname:"/",
    a:[{
        href:"/x.css",
        otherattribute:true
    },{
        href:"/",
        otherattribute:false
    }]
},{
    _id:"deadbeefdeadbeef01234568",
    hostname:"www.example.com",
    pathname:"/other",
    a:[{
        href:"/resource",
        otherattribute:true
    },{
        href:"/"
    }]
}
```

I have an aggregate which through the miracle of MongoDB returns a list of unique links as such:

```
{
    _id:"www.example.com",
    items:[
        "/",
        "/x.css",
        "/resource"
    ]
}
```

I am then returning this in Node.JS and using it as such:

```
aeach(items,async function(i,iv){
    //! Where i == index and iv == link string

    let result = await db("dbname")
        .collection("webpages")
        .findOne({
            pathname:iv
        })

    if(!result){
        candidate = iv;
        return true;
    }
})
```

The aggregation I have to return unique links is great and very performant but when I have a large web structure that I am crawling, I need to do potentially thousands of lookups to find a webpage I have not attempted to visit yet. `aeach` is a `forEach` like operator which uses an `async function` callback. Returning `true` inside this function will `break` the loop and `false` with `continue` the loop.

So the question is:

How can I return only a list of strings which do not correspond to any documents `pathname` field (has not had an attempted visit yet)

Edit:

My current aggregation is as follows:

```
[{
    $match: {
        hostname: scope.connection.hostname
    }
},{
    $project: {
        a: "$a"
    }
},{
    $unwind: {
        path: "$a"
    }
},{                             // Remove some junk elements
    $match:{
        "a.href": {
            $not: /(#|link)/gi
        }
    }
},{
    $group: {
        _id: scope.connection.hostname,
        items: {
            $addToSet: "$a"
        }
    }
}]
```

Comment: isnt pathname in the root of each object the page you visited? you can filter by those first

Comment: I've added my current pipeline. It is certainly centred on the 'a' field. How would you organise this differently?

Comment: what do u mean by list of strings which do not correspond to any documents pathname. sorry couldnt understand very well

Answer (score 0):

I believe [`$setDifference`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) is what you are looking for.

You can `$group` the pathnames, and the items ("a"), and then use `$setDifference` to retreive only what exist in `items` but not in `pathnames` (hence, only un-visited links).

```js
// [...]
{
    $group: {
        _id: scope.connection.hostname,
        pathnames: {
            $addToSet: "$pathname",
        },
        items: {
            $addToSet: "$a",
        },
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        items: {
            $setDifference: [ "$items", "$pathnames" ],
        },
    },
}]
```